# Play framework multiple file upload

Tags: playframework

I try to upload multiple files with one request but it always error, My view code:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

And:

```
public static void doUpload(File[] files) {
    File dir = new File(Play.applicationPath+File.separator+"public"+File.separator+"uploads");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    boolean success = files.renameTo(new File(dir, files.getName()));
    if (!success) {
        renderText("{'success':'true', 'msg':{'url':'"+files.getName()+"'}}");
    } else {
        renderText("{'success':'true'}");
    }
}
```

If I use single file upload with `<input type="file" name="files">` and parameters in controllor using `File files`, then it works fine.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple inputs with the same name, the controller will receive those files with the given name as an array, e.g.

Controller:

```
public static void upload(File[] files) {
    ...
}
```

View:

```
#{form @upload(), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
<input type="file" name="files">
<input type="file" name="files">
<input type="file" name="files">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
#{/form}
```

You can always add a bit of javascript to allow the user to add additional inputs on the client side

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in Play 1.2.5 with the multiple tag in `<input type="file" name="files" multiple>`.  The only problem I see with the original posters code was `name="files[]"` which should have been `name="files"`

It may have been the case that there was also a bug in an earlier version of Play, but this just worked for me (I selected 50 files with one file input)